# How to populate a $0-$line with $1$'s?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binary, constraint-programming

I have a line of $n$ $0$'s like this:

> Zeroth index -->$000...000$

I want to populate the line with $m$ $1$'s with the following rules:

> (1) They have to occur after the index $i_{\text{start}_n}$ and before the index $i_{\text{end}_n}$.
>
> (2) There must be *at least* three $0$'s between any two $1$'s.
>
> (3) The positions are random within the above two constraints.
>
> (4) $i_{\text{start}_n}<i_{\text{end}_n}<n-1$
>
> (5) $\color{red}{m<?}$

How can this insertion be performed, and what are the constraints on $\color{red}{m}$?

Comment: You should know that I'm using this in order to populate my event list with ads. You see, I fetch the event database array size and I need to populate $m$ ads randomly within it.

Comment: Legal: `...0001000...` Legal: `...1000100001...` Illegal: `...0001001...` Illegal: `...000101...` Illegal: `...11...` *et cetera*

Comment: Oh, got it. Yeah, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Symbolically, what does $m$ have to be?

Comment: I'm will be translating this model into PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a zero to each side of each $1$, then insert the $m$ "$010$" units into a line of $(n-2m)$ zeroes (including potentially before and after).

This is possible in ${n-2m+1 \choose m}$ ways.

Clearly we need $(n-2m+1) \ge m \implies m \le \frac{n+1}{3}$

---

Algorithmically, finding positions for the $m$ $1$s can use the above insertion process as follows:

- Find $n'= i_{end}-i_{start}+1$
- Randomly choose $m$ distinct numbers in the range $0$ to $(n'-2m)$
- With the numbers in ascending order $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m\}$, modify them by adding $2(k-1)+i_{start}$ to each $a_k$.
- These values are insertion points in the string of $0$s - they do not refer to position in the final string. Each $1$ goes after the $0$ at the indicated position.

Comment: I didn't actually do the obvious check on a maximally populated result string (like $0100010001000100010$), but now that I do, it matches the above result.

Comment: I didn't understand the indexing thing at first reading, but now I'm looking at it again I think I understand what you are saying... Not a huge revision, you just need to subdivide out the portion of the string that the $1$s are allowed to occupy.

Comment: I think I'm looking for an insertion method, as it were. Like a set of ad indices that perfectly arrange the ads between the constraining indices such that they're spaced correctly *vis-a-vis* the rules.

Comment: @Adam - added an algorithm

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
            $numbers = range($min, $max);
            shuffle($numbers);
            return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}

for( $i=0 ; $i < 20 ; $i++ ){//20 instances

    $numbers = UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0, 204-1-3-9+1-2*10, 10);//204 events

    sort($numbers);

    echo var_dump($numbers)."<br/>";//show numbers before adding 2(k-1)+i_start

    foreach( $numbers as $key=>$num ){
         $numbers[$key] = $num+2*($key+1-1)+9;
    }

    echo "FINAL ARRAY: ";
    echo var_dump($numbers)."<br/><br/>";//show numbers after adding 2(k-1)+i_start
}

?>
```

Comment: @Joffan, I get a $7$ using your method with a start index of $9$.

Comment: Go to http://phpfiddle.org/, click "CodeSpace", copy my updated code into the console, then click "Run - F9".

Comment: @Joffan, when you say "between" do you mean end-point-noninclusive? $[0,n^{'}-2m]$ or $(0,n^{'}-2m)$

Comment: I think you mean $(0,n^{'}-2m)$, and I figured out why I was getting a $7$: It's because `$numbers` is a 0-index array, and your solution requires $a_1, ...$, which is as 1-index set.

Comment: Actually, I think you mean $[0,n^{'}-2m]$, right?

Comment: In LaTeX, it's just n' to get $n'$, not n^' to get $n^{'}$.

Comment: @Adam - the "@name"  only works to alert people already involved in a conversation (and the owner of the post - you in this case), which is why I had not responded earlier. The numbers available to chose include both $0$ and $(n'-2m)$.